# How to abort or fail a Visual Studio build if a postbuild event runs a program that returns an error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, post-build-event

Can the build of a Visual Studio solution with many projects be aborted if a postbuild event for one project return some error code back to Visual Studio? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found this: [article](http://geekswithblogs.net/dchestnutt/archive/2006/05/30/80113.aspx)
exit 1 means postbuild event fails